# Mostrar varios valores como selected de un select multiple en PHP

Tags: php, select

Tengo un select multiple, que funciona correctamente a la hora de recoger los datos. También hace correctamente la inserción en la BBDD. El problema me ocurre al mostrar en el select, las opciones que están "selected" ya que solo me marca la primera que lee de la tabla.

```
<?php
    $query6 = mysqli_query($link,"select * from rangoedades");
    $array_ = explode(",",$row['rango_edad']);
    ?>  
    <select name="idrangos[]" data-placeholder="rangos" class="select-search" multiple="multiple">
      <?php
      foreach ($array_ as $rango1) { 
        while($row6=mysqli_fetch_array($query6)) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row6['id_rango_edad']; ?>"
            <?php if($row6['id_rango_edad']==$rango1) { echo ' selected = "selected" '; } ?> ><?php echo $row6['nombre']; ?>
          </option>
        <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>

?>
```

La inserción como digo la hace correctamente de esta manera.

```
<?php

  $idrangos=$_POST['idrangos'];

  $rango_ = array();

  foreach ($idrangos as $idrango) {
    array_push($rango_, $idrango);
  }

  $rango_final = implode(",", $rango_);

?>
```

siendo "$rango_final" el valor que inserto en la tabla.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hay que ver si son comparables y correspondientes los valores de ambos datasets. Dentro del `while`, justo después de abrir la llave, coloca un `var_dump($row6['id_rango_edad'], $rango1);` para verificar.

Comment: Hola. Acabo de conseguir solucionarlo. A veces es mejor dejarlo quieto un rato y volver mas tarde. Ha bastado con cambiar la ubicación de foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Así queda finalmente:

```
<?php
    $query6 = mysqli_query($link,"select * from rangoedades");
    $array_ = explode(",",$row['rango_edad']);
    ?>  
    <select name="idrangos[]" data-placeholder="rangos" class="select-search" multiple="multiple">
      <?php
        while($row6=mysqli_fetch_array($query6)) { var_dump($row6)?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row6['id_rango_edad']; ?>" 
            <?php
            foreach ($array_ as $rango1) { 
              if($row6['id_rango_edad']==$rango1) { 
                echo 'selected="selected"'; 
              } 
            } ?> 
            >
            <?php echo $row6['nombre']; ?>
          </option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

En vez de recorrer cada vez `$array_`  dentro del bucle `while` podrías optimizar verificando si el valor está en `$array_` mediante el uso de [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php).

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
    $query6 = mysqli_query($link,"select * from rangoedades");
    $array_ = explode(",",$row['rango_edad']);
      
    $html='<select name="idrangos[]" data-placeholder="rangos" class="select-search" multiple="multiple">';
    while($row6=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query6)) {
          $s=in_array($row6['id_rango_edad'], $array_) ? "selected" : "";
          $html.="<option value=\"$row6[id_rango_edad]\" $s>$row6[nombre]</option>";
        } 
    $html.="</select>";
    echo $html;
?>
```

Aquí hay otras optimizaciones, aparte de evitar la horrible mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML, que en este caso concreto permite no solo darle claridad al código, sino reducirlo considerablemente.

Te comento lo que se ha ido haciendo:

1. He sustituido el método `mysqli_fetch_array` por otro más específico: `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, esto porque el primero te trae los datos dos veces, como array numérico y asociativo, pudiendo esto tener impactos en el rendimiento rendimiento en contextos con muchos datos o con muchas conexiones. `mysqli_fetch_assoc` trae los datos una sola vez, como array asociativo, que es el tipo de uso que requieres aquí.
2. Mediante `in_array()` verificamos con un ternario si el valor existe en `$array_`. Si es así, la variable `$s` adquirirá el valor `selected`, sino, quedará en blanco. Con poner `selected` basta, no es necesario poner: `selected="selected"`... Al mismo tiempo, construimos todo el `option` junto (esto es posible gracias a concatenar en una sola variable `$html`).

Ya está, no hay más historias. Tienes un código optimizado, más breve, y mucho más legible y fácil de mantener.

### Recomendación

Muchas de las funciones del estilo procedural son obsoletas desde PHP 7. Considera modernizar tu código, adoptando el estilo orientado a objeto de mysqli.